# How to zoom-in to the point under the mouse cursor (Processing)

Tags: processing

I'd like to zoom-in to the point under the mouse cursor in a [Processing](http://processing.org/) sketch. The scale part of the problem is pretty straightforward; it's the translate part that I can't figure out. The idea is to be able to zoom-in to a Processing sketch, whilst maintaining the relative distance between the objects in the sketch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. A basic sketch, which zooms-in but doesn't maintain the relative distance, follows:

```
float scaleFactor;
void setup()
{
    size(300, 300);
    scaleFactor = 1;
}

void draw()
{
    background(255);
    fill(128);
    noStroke();
    pushMatrix();
    scale(scaleFactor);
    rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed()
{
    if (key == 'r')
    {
        scaleFactor = 1;
    }
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e)
{
    scaleFactor += e.getAmount() / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The previous answer doesn't quite have the requested behavior. If you want the same style of zooming as users might expect from scrolling the mouse in Google Maps, for example, I think you want this:

```
float scaleFactor = 1.0;
float translateX = 0.0;
float translateY = 0.0;

void setup() {
    size(300, 300);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(128);
    noStroke();
    pushMatrix();
    translate(translateX,translateY);
    scale(scaleFactor);
    rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    rect(width-100, height-100, 100, 100);
    popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed() {
    if (key == 'r') {
        scaleFactor = 1;
        translateX = 0.0;
        translateY = 0.0;
    }
}

void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    translateX += mouseX - pmouseX;
    translateY += mouseY - pmouseY;
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e) {
    translateX -= mouseX;
    translateY -= mouseY;
    float delta = e.getCount() > 0 ? 1.05 : e.getCount() < 0 ? 1.0/1.05 : 1.0;
    scaleFactor *= delta;
    translateX *= delta;
    translateY *= delta;
    translateX += mouseX;
    translateY += mouseY;
}
```

Comment: Hey I know this is super old but would you mind adding a short explanation as to how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
float scaleFactor;
float translateX;
float translateY;
void setup()
{
  size(300, 300);

  scaleFactor = 1;
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);

  fill(128);

  noStroke();

  pushMatrix();

  translate(translateX,translateY);
  scale(scaleFactor);

  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  rect(width-100, height-100, 100, 100);

  popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == 'r')
  {
    scaleFactor = 1;
  }
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e)
{
  translateX = translateX-e.getAmount()*(mouseX)/100;
  translateY = translateY-e.getAmount()*(mouseY)/100;
  scaleFactor += e.getAmount() / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's smoother to do:

```
float e = -event.getCount()/100.0;
float delta = pow(2, e);
```

instead of:

```
float delta = e.getCount() > 0 ? 1.05 : e.getCount() < 0 ? 1.0/1.05 : 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a detailed answer on why RandomEtc's answer works.

Key part of their answer is:

```
void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e) {
    translateX -= mouseX;
    translateY -= mouseY;
    float delta = e.getCount() > 0 ? 1.05 : e.getCount() < 0 ? 1.0/1.05 : 1.0;
    scaleFactor *= delta;
    translateX *= delta;
    translateY *= delta;
    translateX += mouseX;
    translateY += mouseY;
}
```

This works because we do 3 transformations: translate by [-mouseX, -mouseY], scale by [delta, delta], translate by [+mouseX, +mouseY].

The translation is important because scaling scales 'about the origin' (i.e. the origin remains constant, all other points change). So we translate to move the origin, then translate back at the end.

In terms of [matrix transformations](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/02/10/tranfsormation-matrix/), we can express this as the following (where `mx = mouseX`, `my = mouseY`, `d = delta`):

```
 -        -    -        -    -          -
| 1  0  mx |  |  d  0  0 |  |  1  0  -mx |
| 0  1  mY |  |  0  d  0 |  |  0  1  -my |
| 0  0  1  |  |  0  0  1 |  |  0  0  1   |
 -        -    -        -    -          -
```

Also, note that the order is important, as matrix operations are not commutative. While the order may seem non-intuitive (they are in the opposite order!) - this is because we would write a point on the right-hand end of the transformation matrices and apply from the right to the left. Anyway.

If you carry out the matrix multiplication, you end up with:

```
 -               -
|  d  0  mx*(1-d) |
|  0  d  my*(1-d) |
|  0  0  1        |
 -               -
```

Or, scaling by `delta` and translating by `mouseX * (1 - delta)`. Which is equivalent to `mouseX - mouseX * delta`. This is exactly what RandomEtc does. An equivalent function would be:

```
void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e) {
    float delta = e.getCount() > 0 ? 1.05 : e.getCount() < 0 ? 1.0/1.05 : 1.0;
    scaleFactor *= delta;
    translateX = (delta*translateX) + mouseX * (1 - delta);
    translateY = (delta*translateY) + mouseY * (1 - delta);
}
```